# Access 2013, web app, how to display Name of the employee in combo box, but to save person's ID in table in back-end?

Tags: sharepoint

I my Access 2013 web app, I have two tables. One is Employees and another one is TimeSheet. Table Employees contains following columns/records

E_ID   |   Name

1        Jack Nicholson

2        Robert De Niro

TimeSheet table contains columns: E_ID, Date, Time.

I have created new web form based on TimeSheet table and my goal is that user can choose list of Employees from Combo box, and after user had selected employee, he goes to Save button. In that moment, value from Combo box should be saved in TimeSheet table BUT that should be E_ID of employee, NOT the Name of the employee.

For example, if user chooses Jack Nicholson, then in E_ID column of Timesheet table, value '1' should be stored.

Many thanks in advance.

With kind regards.
Adi

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi blm, I have tried this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/756574 but I always end up with saving Name of employee instead of E_ID and that is the main issue. However, in meantime I have found one interesting topic which describes similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681269/access-2013-web-app-multi-value-lookup Right now, I am struggling to figure out how to solve it using Data macro;( Again, any help is appreciated. With kind regards. Adi